# Ansible not picking up my hosts file when used with a galaxy installed role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Here's my directory structure:

```
group_vars/qa/vars.yml
install.yml
hosts
```

with  my hosts file looking like this:

```
[qa]
my.ip.address.here ansible_ssh_user=admin
my.ip.address.here2 ansible_ssh_user=admin
```

and my install.yml file looks like this:

```
---
- name: Setup the mysql database servers
  hosts: qa
  roles:
    - role: geerlingguy.mysql
      become: yes
      mysql_root_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
      mysql_enabled_on_startup: yes
      mysql_databases: name={{ mysql_database_name }} 
      mysql_users: name={{ mysql_user_name }} password={{ mysql_user_password }}
      mysql_slow_query_log_enabled: yes
      mysql_slow_query_log_file: /var/log/mysql-slow.log
      mysql_slow_query_time: 2
```

But when I run the playbook, I get the following error:

```
PLAY [Setup the mysql database servers] ****************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

Am I missing something with how I've defined my hosts file? Is the 'roles' block correct in the above setup?

Answer (score 1):

Grr... dumb question.

I had forgotten to add an ansible.cfg file for my new playbook, which I normally use to point to the hostfile in my local directory. Doh.